# Trying to create a search system

Tags: javascript, json

My html

```
 <input type="text" placeholder="Search Posts" class="filterPosts"/>

    <ul class="postsList">

    </ul>
```

My Posts.json
But I think this right, because I don't make anything here

```
{
  "posts" : [
    {
      "name" : "Como fazer um SearchBox",
      "url" : "https://google.com",
      "description": "blablavlablablabla bla blablabla"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Melhores apps para programar",
      "url" : "https://youtube.com",
      "description": "blablavlablablabla bla blablabla"
    },
    {
      "name" : "Como fazer PIPOCA!",
      "url" : "https://epic5.netlify.com",
      "description": "blablavlablablabla bla blablabla"
    },
    {
      "name": "Como fazer pipoca quente na manteiga!",
      "url": "https://google.com",
      "description": "pipoca r mt bom"
    },
    {
      "name": "Como dançar beat it",
      "url": "https://google.com",
      "description": "pipoca r mt bom"
    }
  ]
}
```

My code

```
let inputS = document.querySelector('.filterPosts');
let inputSearch = inputS.value.toUpperCase();
let pList = document.querySelector('.postsList');
let allLi = document.getElementsByTagName('li');

let requestURL = 'Posts.json';
let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open('GET', requestURL);

request.responseType = 'json'; request.send();

request.onload = function() {
  let posts = request.response; 
  showPosts(posts);
  search(posts);
}

function showPosts(jsonObj) {
  let posts = jsonObj['posts'];
  for (let i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {

     let listContent = document.createElement('a');
     listContent.textContent = posts[i].name;
     listContent.href = posts[i].url;

      let liItem = document.createElement('li'); 
      liItem.appendChild(listContent);
      pList.appendChild(liItem);

  }
}

function search(jsonObj) {
  let t = jsonObj['posts'];
  for (let i = 0; i < t.length; i++) {
    txtValue = t[i].name;

    if (txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputSearch) > -1) {
      allLi[i].style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      allLi[i].style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
}


  inputS.addEventListener('keyup',function(){
    search();
  });
```

the error is inside search function (let t = jsonObj['posts'];) when typing anything in the search input, it returns undefined

Please help :( I'm trying to compare the value that is in the json t[i].name with the value entered in the input but I can not

Comment: please, show the Posts.json file if possible to see the your target data format, and add the jsonObj function code as well pls

Comment: `the error`... what is the error? Of course `search` returns `undefined`, you don't have a return statement in that function! You posted too much irrelevant code. Create a minimally reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example.

Comment: @chipit24 ok... I go see

Comment: @fengo look, I add the posts.json

Comment: You call `search()` in the keyup handler with no params so clearly `jsonObj` is undefined in the function itself and the error should be telling you such

Comment: @charlietfl so I need call the param ?

Comment: That object has to get there somehow

Comment: @charlietfl hmmmm, how I can do it?

Comment: Need to make it accessible first

Comment: @charlietfl can you help me please? :(

Comment: instead of scoping `let posts = request.response;` in function.... declare `let posts` outside function and just do `posts = request.response` then that variable is in scope in the keyup handler also so you can call `search(posts)` there also...just make sure it's not undefined also

Comment: Can you post the HTML you are using? That would help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the bug in your code, I have it working [here](https://codepen.io/babbott1000/pen/KjLgoL), I took out the `XMLHttpRequest` and just put it in a variable.  The problem was that you were calling the `search()` function without any parameters at the end of your program.  I also changed the compare line to

```
txtValue.toUpperCase().indexOf(inputSearch) == 0
```

because I thought that made more sense, although you could also change it to `> -1` like you had it if you wanted it to search the whole thing.  I hope this helps.  The other thing I changed is that I added a line in the `search()` function that checked the input valued and updated it, the code for that is

```
let inputSearch = inputS.value.toUpperCase();
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks man, this is really I'm want but this search onle the first word, and if I search for "PIPOCA" don't appear nothing :(

Comment: If you don’t want it to search only the first part and want it to search the whole thing then change the part where it checks the indexOf the search term to greater than -1

Comment: If you find this answer helpful, you can upvote it by clicking the upward arrow

Comment: Not the comment, the answer